# How can i send data from chrome extension to localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-chrome-extension, cross-browser

I am creating a **google chrome** extension to read my History of browser. All works done. Now i am willing to **send the retrieved history data to my localhost server**. Is this possible? How to do this? Please anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The basic steps (sample code contained in the following links) would be:

1. Add your local server url to `permissions` field in `manifest.json`
2. Use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), [Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications), [Nativemessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) (You would need `nativeMessaging` permission instead), or any other communication method to exchange data between extension and your local server.

Answer (score 0):

Second version would be via app network in Chrome https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network

But this requires more low level programming.

Comment: hello dear, i want a complete solution to send data in my localhost server. would you please help me anyway? @cobuz alexandru

Answer (score -2):

Simply post your data to localhost server.

Just remember to add permission in manifest.json.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 1,      
    "name": "Your Extension",
    ...

    "permissions": [
        ....
        "http://localhost:1234/"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is the '1234' port number? Actually i need to know the total process with example code.