# JQuery ajax plus python flask in chrome gives error net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write my very first Chrome Extension. Unfortunately my knowledge and skills of javascript are very limited. Thus I would appreciate simple answer with full working code.

How to send JSON to localhost:1234 from chrome extension? Actually I just want to send string, but if it will be packed in JSON it will be so much easier to parse on the server side. Actually what my server will do is just to append these strings to a txt file (not implemented yet), but it seemed to close to impossible to access filesystem from chrome extension. Thus this is already a work around, because I thought it would be simple enough to contact server from a web browser and it's extension.

I though I found a perfect solution already from here: [How can i send data from chrome extension to localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046395/how-can-i-send-data-from-chrome-extension-to-localhost) I thought: perfect, Websocket is part of the html5 standard, why didn't I find this solution earlier. Unfortunately, chrome gives me this error:

> There were warnings when trying to install this extension: 'sockets'
>   is only allowed for packaged apps, but this is a extension.

Now I switched to second option Ajax and got little further. 
Here is the script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a:contains('BibTeX')").click(function(e) {
    var $a = $(this);
    $.get(this.href, function(data) {
      var $b = $(this);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://localhost:5000/api/append_bib_file',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({bibentry: data}),
      });

      $a.html("Sended to server");
      setTimeout(function() {$a.html("Append to BibTeX file")}, 1000);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
  }).html("Append to BibTeX file");
```

Here is the append_file_server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/api/append_bib_file', methods=['POST'])
def say_name():
    json = request.get_json()
    bibitem = json['bibitem']
    print("Hello World!!!")
    print(bibitem)
    return jsonify(hello="Hello World!!!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,ssl_context=('/Users/tfrondel/.localhost-ssl/cert.pem','/Users/tfrondel/.localhost-ssl/key.pem'))
```

And here is the manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Google Scholar Write Bibtex",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Show Bibtex on Google Scholar Search Page",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://scholar.google.be/*", "http://scholar.google.be/*",
        "https://scholar.google.ca/*", "http://scholar.google.ca/*",
        "https://scholar.google.com.hk/*", "http://scholar.google.com.hk/*",
        "https://scholar.google.com/*", "http://scholar.google.com/*",
        "https://scholar.google.co.jp/*", "http://scholar.google.co.jp/*",
        "https://scholar.google.co.uk/*", "http://scholar.google.co.uk/*",
        "https://scholar.google.de/*", "http://scholar.google.de/*",
        "https://scholar.google.dk/*", "http://scholar.google.dk/*",
        "https://scholar.google.es/*", "http://scholar.google.es/*",
        "https://scholar.google.fi/*", "http://scholar.google.fi/*",
        "https://scholar.google.fr/*", "http://scholar.google.fr/*",
        "https://scholar.google.it/*", "http://scholar.google.it/*",
        "https://scholar.google.nl/*", "http://scholar.google.nl/*",
        "https://scholar.google.no/*", "http://scholar.google.no/*",
        "https://scholar.google.pt/*", "http://scholar.google.pt/*",
        "https://scholar.google.se/*", "http://scholar.google.se/*"
      ],
      "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "clipboard.min.js", "script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions":  [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "clipboardWrite" ,
    "http://localhost/*"
    "https://localhost/*"
  ],

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

This is the error message:

> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST https://localhost:5000/api/append_bib_file
>   net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

I hope I have a simple beginner's mistake, which can be fixed easily.

Comment: ** Access-Control-Allow-Origin** ?

Comment: Thanks for proposal. If I understood correctly you will mean starting chrome like this: Chrome  --disable-web-security --user-data-dir. This gives warning:  you are using unsupported command line flag: --disable-web-security .... Plus it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I also tried this: http://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Still the same problem.

Comment: I found a solution: https://deliciousbrains.com/https-locally-without-browser-privacy-errors/, but some idiot deleted from the answers.